# PublicKey.toString() vs PublicKey.toBase58()

Tags: web3.js

@solana/web3.js has 2 ways to convert a public key to string. what's the difference between PublicKey.toString() and PublicKey.toBase58()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are absolutely identical. In the source code, the `toString()` method simply returns a call to `toBase58()`, as seen here:

```
/**
 * Return the base-58 representation of the public key
 */
toString(): string {
  return this.toBase58();
}
```

[Here is the source for that on GitHub on line 134 in the referenced commit.](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/ddb5d7be494a3ee89d6071aec270c3efde89d4cf/src/publickey.ts#L134)